# Is the force experienced by one jumping into a stagnant body of water and a body such as a river similar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, aerodynamics

Is the force experienced similar or different? By how much? Suppose the height from which the person is falling is 25 m and the mass is 85 kg.

Comment: Force, of person, or river,,,,in what direction ? Are you familiar with vectors (and also that we don't answer homework type question :).

Comment: @count_to_10 this doesn't seem obviously like homework question to me - he isn't asking you to calculate a number using a vector diagram.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird      it 100 percent looks   homeworky to  me :) even if I am wrong, the get out is homework-type. I don't have enough details to give an answer without vectors. **Is the force  jumping into a stagnant body of water or a river similar?** The force at what point is not specified, says it's a deep, very  strongly flowing river, then as soon as he enters the water, there will be a component of horizontal movement. My interpretation is overall force, not just downward directed  gravity. I could be wrong, I definitely have a bad habit of misreading questions.

Comment: @count_to_10 Well I can't be sure either... I read it as a musing between friends who were overlooking a bridge, and really mean impulse instead of force... in which case its at least a bit interesting to consider what extent of the river's motion would affect impact.